# JsFiddle with Jasmine 2.2 No Specs Found

Tags: jasmine, jsfiddle

I was not able to find any JSFiddle examples with Jasmine 2.2 so I decided to create my own.  Despite including all the Jasmine JavaScript files it still complains that there are No Specs Found.  What am I missing please?

http://jsfiddle.net/gfinzer/dgrwtc6k/3/

```
describe("Common tests", function() {

    it("ExtractNumbers method should extract numbers from a string", function () {
        expect(ExtractNumbers("Logan 5, Francis 7")).toBe("57");
    });

});

function ExtractNumbers(text) {
    if (!text)
        return text;

    return text.replace( /\D+/g, '');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right. Is just the setup for Fiddle. Use 'No wrap - in head'.

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Stuff</title> 
<script> 
/* your code */ 
</script> 
</head>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/40xk6hfv/